# In What Method Do I Set The Redirect URI When Using Facebook's Javascript SDK for oAuth Dialog?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

This should be a straightforward question, but I can't figure it out. Where do I set the redirect uri and scopes at when trying to oAuth login using the FB Javascipt SDK?

Thanks!

Comment: There should be no need to specify a redirect_uri at all, in most cases the SDK will handle that for you (and if yours should not be one of those, then you’ll have to be more specific). And where to put the scope is clearly documented, so what problem do you have with that?

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for the reply. I'm getting a dialog box, but once I login, the box doesn't close and the browser title says "Redirecting", but it never closes nor does the referring page reload.